# Volume low even at maximum

Tags: sound

I have an Asus UL20FT-A1 laptop whose sound at maximum is not high enough. I have to open the Sound Settings menu and go over the limitation to get a high enough level. Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Try the PCM settings in `alsamixer`:

- Open terminal: *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>*
- Type `alsamixer`

[image]

You may need to select the sound card with <kbd>**F6**</kbd> first.

Turning up all the other controls may also help [image: smiley]

Comment: Thanks for the hint! For some reason media keys got broken on 16.10 after upgrade.

Comment: On Windows this never happens, volume controls just work. Why does it happen on Linux?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin - AFAIK the PCM setting should by default be at max, just adding or modifying certain software or hardware may change that. Like with Windows and default audio devices :)

Comment: @Wilf It is not the first time i have to use alsamixer to unmute or increase volumes on Ubuntu and Fedora. It is like it is initialised with random values. IMO, the volume control UI must do that, this step must be absolutely unnecessary. Just venting in general.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I would ask about it then but if it is two distros it may be a bug, probably for that specific hardware (as in driver / sound server - software is also possible but Fedora and Ubuntu usually use slightly different versions, unless you have both installed with the same version)

Comment: @Wilf It is a usability bug. I observed it in the last 5-10 years, with different versions of Fedora and Ubuntu and different audio hardware.

Comment: @Wilf It is like there are two levels of volume settings and the UI tools operate on one level, alsamixer on another.

Comment: didn't work for bluetooth speaker :-(

Comment: @PhilippMunin The issue may those often have a independently operated amplifier on the speaker itself (usually controlled via buttons on it). OR you need to select to use A2DP output instead of the (much lower quality) HSP in sound settings.

Comment: @Wilf thanks for response, but none of that worked. Volume of bluetooth device is on max, and the beep sound it makes - is very loud, but the computer sounds its outputting is very low volume.  I use A2DP, but worth to note A2DP's volume is lower volume than the HSP's

Comment: @PhilippMunin may be worth asking a question then! Screenshots of speaker settings, `alsamixer` etc would help :)

Comment: Thank you so much... was having the same issue here.

Comment: Boosted the volume for my USB headphones, specifically Bloody J473. Thanks!

Comment: thanks a lot. definitely a lifesaver. I wondered why my newly bought headphone has volume lower than the budget headset. hehe

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I've had this happen a bunch of times on Windows (at least with previous versions, I haven't used 10/11 as much), sometimes without remedy - the OS just seems to set min at 0%, max at 10% for a particular device, which works normally elsewhere or even via linux on the same machine giving 0-100% or 0-150% etc.

Comment: I don't know what this did. Messing around with the settings, first got rid of audio completely, but then messing around with it a bit more brought the audio back and fixed it.

Comment: I don´t really understand why, but my primary audio output device (i.e. USB audio) was set to -89dB in Alsamixer. I corrected it to 0dB and that solved my issue.

Answer (score 63):

**1. Open terminal**
`Ctrl` + `Alt` + `T`

**2. Install PavuControl** `sudo apt install pavucontrol`

**3. Open PulseAudio Volume Control** `pavucontrol`

**4. Output devices** 
Set to 100% (0dB) the port are you using (*Speakers / Headphones etc*)

[image]

Comment: After I adjusted levels in `alsamixer` the volume was still seemingly lower than on Windows or when pairing my headphones with a phone. This is what actually helped me (in case anyone encounter the same issue)

Comment: Same here. With alsamixer nothing changed. But when adjusting from `pavucontrol` it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

You should enable "Louder than 100%" in sound settings.
This works at least in Ubuntu 17.10
[image: Screenshot]

Update:
Pop!_OS 21.01:
[image]

Comment: This is also there is 16.04 in sound settings

Comment: that was the solution for me

Comment: This feature is indeed available, but don't be surprised if you find the sound quality unacceptable: https://askubuntu.com/a/1316929/1157519 (Bonus: for me the solution was finding and fixing the dialled-down bars in alsamixer.)

Comment: This answer actually solved my problem.

Answer (score 6):

This works 100%...

- right click on volume icon located at top right corner of screen (ubuntu 16 )
- Select sound settings
- Go to application section and raise volume up :D enjoy your high sound..

Comment: Definitely not a silver bullet and silly to suggest it might be so. Having said that, this worked for me so thumbs up.

Comment: That particular context menu item doesn't seem to exist on Ubuntu 18.

Comment: By alsamix (or an alternative) you can raise eventually the limit beyond the settings you mention. The reason to do so is that afterwards you can adjust speakers easier to the volume range of different sources which might be too silent otherwise even if you adjust maximum.

Answer (score 3):

If you were using GNOME 3, definitely you don't need `pavucontrol` or `alsamixer`. Instead just use `gnome-tweaks` to enable over-amplification (in the General tab, or in the Audio tab if any)

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed for me by installing `pavucontrol` per [Sorin Veștemean's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390734/volume-low-even-at-maximum/1108944#1108944), going to the **Configuration** tab and altering my USB headset output format to *analog stereo output + mono input*, going back to the **Output Devices** tab and bumping THAT output's volume up to 100% (it was at something like 50%).

Opinion: The fact that Ubuntu fails to retain my audio output settings through reboots and seemingly randomizes the configuration until I go in and manually fix it half the time *with a custom-installed tool* is a ridiculous usability issue.

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me! Using analog instead of digital output boosts the volume considerably to the same level experienced on Windows. Over-amplification is no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

This has been an intermittent problem for me. Sound works perfectly fine in windows, but is often low or distored in Ubuntu. Most of the suggested fixes have not worked for me.

I have however found a workaround solution, which is to pair Ubuntu to Alexa via  bluetooth "Alexa, Pair" and use her as my in-room speaker. I get full volume without any distortion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LUBUNTU you might need to try `pavucontrol` in terminal. In my custom setup ubuntu core + openbox + lxdp I have `pavucontrol` managing sounds.

Answer (score 1):

I faced volume low issue, I fixed by setting Zoom Application Volume to max.

Settings -> Sound -> Applications
[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tdf1N.png)

Note : I see Zoom volume control available under Applications tab only when Zoom is running.

Ubuntu version I am running : 18.04.4 LTS

My Zoom version : 5.0.413237.0524

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04:

From **Terminal**, I open **pavucontrol** (no need to install it, it is there by default), and below are the settings I did and which raised the volume on the speakers automatically:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When the microphone level on the system settings is > 100% (and it sometimes seems to adjust itself to > 100%) in my setting the microphone becomes almost completely silenced. The solution is to make sure that the microphone level stays < 100%.

To test microphone settings the best is to record oneself and listen to the recording.

Answer (score 0):

It sounded very very very low to me and my solution with a Realtek ALC1220 card was to increase the volume of **"Headphone"** in alsamixer

[image: Alsamixer screenshot]