# Is it possible to increase the laptop's sound beyond of the standard-limit

Tags: sound

I would like know if is possible to increase the laptop sound volume beyond of the default. For example, instead of you put at 100%, put at 200%.

Thanks very much.

Comment: That would sound … horrible. The distortion would cause headaches. Either way, some sound cards do allow it. Which audio device is in your computer?

Answer (score 1):

I have this possibility. Matigo [mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1316854/is-it-possible-to-increase-the-laptops-sound-beyond-of-the-standard-limit#comment2242185_1316854) that it may depend on one's soundcard.

This is how it looks like in the standard settings app (alsamixer visible for comparison):

[image]

The problem with it is how distorted the sound becomes.

The result is comparable to the effect that's called "clipping", or "square signal".

It's unnatural, absolutely un-enjoyable, but most importantly I have the feeling that it amortizes the physical speaker units incredibly fast. It's like it's ripping them apart.

So, except for when I take a screenshot of it for using it in an AskUbuntu answer, I keep this option disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find some useful information about how to increase volume above maximum.
There are described several ways how to do it.

https://superuser.com/questions/300178/can-i-increase-the-sound-volume-above-100-in-linux